# Не получается использовать библиотеку с Obective-C на Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Всем привет, нашел библиотеку MailCore2 для Objective-C, сам пишу проект на Swift, на гитхабе была инструкция, как использовать эту библиотеку в Swift, все сделал, выдает такую ошибку: unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/Apple/Desktop/Ф/Programming/Swiftnew/CivilCalculateDemo/Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

Но Bridging-Header.h cуществует по указанному пути. Не могу понять в чем дело.:(

Comment: а можно инструкцию посмотреть? ну и в любом случае - навскидку, имя хедера неправильное, там где то название проекта должно быть в имени

Comment: Я потом исправлял имя хедера, все равно не помогло, я пересобрал проект и все заработало. И потом я сталкивался с такой же ошибкой в том случае, если я устанавливал библиотеку после того, как начал писать код. Не знаю почему, мне раньше казалось, что библиотеки можно устанавливать когда угодно. Или я делаю что-то неправильно? (устанавливал все по инструкции)